# Is there a Premium Account necesary for the Spotify API?

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to make a Spotify voice control for volume and I can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas? I have been stuck at this for a while and it says `Player command failed: Premium required, reason: PREMIUM_REQUIRED`. Any help would be appreciated

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

auth_manager = SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id="myclientid",
    client_secret="myclientsecret",
    redirect_uri="http://localhost:8888/callback",
    username="username",
    scope="user-modify-playback-state"
)
spotipy = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=auth_manager)

engine = pyttsx3.init()
 
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Listening...')
        r.pause_threshold = 0.5
        r.energy_threshold = 494
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.3)
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print('Recognizing..')
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-us')
        print(f'User said: {query}\n')

    except Exception as e:
        # print(e)

        print('Say that again please...')
        return 'None'
    return query

def LowerVolume():
    spotipy.volume(15)

while True:
        query = takeCommand().lower()
        if "lower volume" in query:
            LowerVolume()
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that API call requires a Premium account. As per [the docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#endpoint-set-volume-for-users-playback):

> If the user making the request is non-premium, a 403 FORBIDDEN response code will be returned.

Comment: Why would that require Premium, it's just volume?

Comment: I don't know, ask Spotify. Maybe so people who want to develop their own apps in the Spotify ecosystem would also pay them?

Comment: @AKX uhm, wrong. The end user needs the premium account, not the dev

Comment: @Hobbamok Sure. In this case, the dev is also the end user.

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2023 the requirement for a Spotify Premium account may have been removed.

The documentation [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/getting-started) now states:

Prerequisites: This tutorial assumes you have a Spotify account (**free or premium**).